# is the HP 4510s dedicated video card removable?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Does anyone know if the dedicated video card of an HP 4510s laptop can be replaced?

The long story is:

I have an HP 4510s laptop with an ATI Radeon HD4330 video card, and recently it had shut down while playing a game. After that, I got no more than a black screen, even though I can hear the PC reading the CD-ROM and trying to boot up.

To check if this is a display problem or not, I connected a cable from the VGA output of my laptop to the VGA input of a monitor, and the monitor still shows a black screen, making me think it is probably the video card that is damaged.

I also tried a hard reset, but nothing changed.

Any other suggestions on how I could fix this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not user replaceable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'dedicated" part means it has got its own video memory, the graphics adapter is still integrated in the system board.  Replace the system board.

Check with HP for part numbers.  Here's a [current link to the Spare Parts list for your notebook](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/performMaintDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=3934828&spf_p.tpst=psiContentDisplay&spf_p.prp_psiContentDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c01747314-19%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#N10038).

Here's the system/motherboard section from that document:

[image]

You'll want to identify which one suits your model's options the best (DDR3? WWAN? etc.), and then pick one that has "discrete graphics".

Your existing system board may also have the part number silk-screened on it someplace.

If you want guarantees it's going to work, take it to an authorized HP repair depot and get them to repair it. :)